# Having trouble selecting id of a shape from a group using Kinetic shape?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I'm having trouble with selecting a `shape` from a `group` using its `id`. This is my codepen: http://codepen.io/drixta/pen/AInHL

Here's my code for creating a square:

```
function create_square(posr,posc,state,len){
var square = new Kinetic.Rect({
    id : "sqr"+ posr + "," + posc,
    posr: posr,
    posc: posc,
    state : state,
    x: posr*len,
    y: posc*len,
    width: len,
    height: len,
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    fill: 'white'
});
console.log(square.attrs.id);
squareGroup.add(square);
}
```

From here everything works fine. The console would printout the id of every square.

```
sqr0,0 javascript.js:44
sqr0,1 javascript.js:44
sqr0,2 javascript.js:44
sqr0,3 javascript.js:44
sqr0,4 javascript.js:44
sqr0,5 javascript.js:44
sqr0,6 javascript.js:44
sqr0,7 javascript.js:44
```

However, according to this site: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-select-shape-by-id-with-kineticjs/

I tried using `console.log((squareGroup.get('#sqr0,0')[0]).attrs.id)` at the end of the program, it says `cannot get attrs of undefined` . Which is assumed this doesn't work.

Thank you very much !

PS: this is the code for highlighting the boxes:

```
square.on("mouseover", function(){
square.setFill('blue');
layer.draw();
});
square.on("mouseout", function(){
square.setFill('white');
layer.draw();
});
```

I nested it in the create_square function and it is extremely slow and unresponsive when the number of box increases, does anyone know where I could do better?

Answer (score 0):

Your example works good with no problem on chrome.

To increase perfomance.
Problem here:

```
square.on("mouseover", function(){
square.setFill('blue');
    layer.draw();
});
square.on("mouseout", function(){
    square.setFill('white');
layer.draw();
});
```

You call layer.draw() twice - it is slow. You can do this:

```
square.on("mouseover", function(){
    square.setFill('blue');
});
square.on("mouseout", function(){
    square.setFill('white');
    setTimeout(function(){layer.draw();});
});
```